# how to make oracle apex wizard steps with multiple related tables?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

In Oracle Apex, I have some related tables i.e:

```
**Person Table**
Id
Name

**Person_Contact Table**
Id
PersonFK
Tel
Address


**Person_Account Table**
Id
PersonFK
BankName
AccountNumber
```

these are 1-to-1 tables and PersonFK is the Foreign Key.
Now, I want to create a wizard with **3 steps**.
how can I do this?

1. should I define 3 tables with 1-to-1 relation (like above) or create just one big table?

and

2. what is the best practice in Oracle Apex (in wizard steps forms) for this purpose?

Comment: There seems to be two unrelated questions here, one about data model design and one about building a wizard-type interface in Apex.

Comment: no it's not..please read carefully.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that all three tables will remain have common attributes then the option of single table is fine. More detail can be find
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9021838/database-design-multiple-tables-vs-a-single-table)